# StringBuilder append String breaks UTF 8

Tags: android, utf-8, stringbuilder

Im sending an XML with HttpPost to a server. This used to wotk fine, and im doing it succesfully in other parts of the project.

Im using a StringBuilder to create the xml request but since i am appending strings as Data to the nodes, i am getting an error response from the parser on the server:

```
Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.
```

When i log the request and check it in w3c xml validator there are no errors.
This is an excerpt (whole method would be to big and has sensitive Data) from my Stringbuilder Method:

```
        StringBuilder baseDocument = new StringBuilder();
        baseDocument.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><request><setDisposalRequest><customer><company><![CDATA[");
        baseDocument.append(company);
        baseDocument.append("]]></company>");
        baseDocument.append("<firstName><![CDATA[");
        baseDocument.append(name);
        baseDocument.append("]]></firstName>");
        ...
```

As soon as i replace the String vars i append with hardcoded Strings, all works fine

i.e

```
baseDocument.append(name);
```

to

```
baseDocument.append("name");
```

All the strings have values, non of them a null or are empty!
Before the request i set the StringEntity to xml

```
se.setContentType("application/xml");
```

what am i missing?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML header claims that it's UTF-8, yet you never mention if you actually *write* UTF-8. Make sure the actual bytes you send are UTF-8 encoded. The error message suggests that you're using another encoding (probably a ISO-8859-* variant).

This is another reason that manually constructing XML like this is dangerous: there are just too many corner cases to observe and it's much easier to use a real XML handling library. Those *tend* to get the corner cases correct ;-)

And no: `StringBuilder` certainly does not break UTF-8. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: ok thx, will do. But homecome it works when i hardcode the Strings like in my example?

Comment: If you send `"name"` then using ISO-88591-* is not a problem, because the UTF-8 encoding and the ISO-8859-1 encoding of that string are the same! (as is true for all strings that are encodable in ASCII). Only if you use non-ASCII characters (such as ä, ö, ß and some punctuation characters) will there be a difference.

Comment: Sweet, thx. Passing the UTF-8 parameter to the StringEntity did the trick. 'se = new StringEntity(reqString,"UTF-8");' And there will be umlauts since the App will be for Austria.I take from your name ur from Ger or At ;)